# How to perform random mutations on a binary np.ndarray based on a probability?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array filled with -1 and 1.

How to perform random mutations with a given probability of mutation (from -1 to 1 or from 1 to -1)?

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
>>> arr
array([[-1,  1,  1],
       [-1, -1, -1],
       [ 1, -1,  1]])

>>> mutation(arr, p=0.2)
array([[-1, -1,  1],
       [-1, -1,  1],
       [ 1, -1,  1]])
```

Here the values at indices [0, 1] and [1, 2] got modified.

With p=1, every values should be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way based on [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) -

```
def mutation(arr, p_val):
    m = np.random.choice([True,False],size=arr.shape,p=[p_val,1-p_val])
    return np.where(m,-np.sign(arr),arr)
```

So, basically with `np.random.choice` we are creating a mask with `p_val` ratio of `True` values and rest are `False`. Then, we use this mask with `np.where` to select elements off `arr` and modify them, i.e. change `1s` to `-1s` and vice versa, while keeping the rest as they are.

Comment: Thank you very much! However it seems that in your case "p_val" represents the probability of **not changing** the values of _arr_. I corrected it by replacing `p=[p_val, 1-p_val]` by `p=[1-p_val, p_val]`.

Comment: @AdrienPavao `p_val` represents probability of number of positions where elements are to be changed. I edited my code after the first post, specifically the last two args of `np.where` were swapped.. Check again?

Comment: Indeed now the behaviour is as expected (reverse `-np.sign(arr)` and `arr` works as well). Thanks again!